# Table sorting not taking into account commas in numerical values

Tags: javascript, html

The following table sorting works mostly fine. However where a value is say 1,495 I would like it to appear above a value of 999 (when that column is sorted highest to lowest). Currently it does not and I am not sure how to fix this:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#999;margin:0px auto;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:12px 12px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#999;color:#444;background-color:#F7FDFA;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:12px 12px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#999;color:#fff;background-color:#26ADE4;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}
th.tg-sort-header::-moz-selection { background:transparent; }th.tg-sort-header::selection      { background:transparent; }th.tg-sort-header { cursor:pointer; }table th.tg-sort-header:after {  content:'';  float:right;  margin-top:7px;  border-width:0 4px 4px;  border-style:solid;  border-color:#404040 transparent;  visibility:hidden;  }table th.tg-sort-header:hover:after {  visibility:visible;  }table th.tg-sort-desc:after,table th.tg-sort-asc:after,table th.tg-sort-asc:hover:after {  visibility:visible;  opacity:0.4;  }table th.tg-sort-desc:after {  border-bottom:;  border-width:4px 4px 0;  }@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;margin: auto 0px;}}</style>
<div class="tg-wrap"><table id="tg-iE8pV" class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">Lender</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Type</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Initial Term (mths)</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Initial Rate (%)</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">SVR (%)</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Overall APR (%)</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Fee (£)</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">LTV (%)</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Max amount (£)</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Max amount (£)</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Monthly Repayment (£)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.98</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.98</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.40</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.98</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.48</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.40</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.28</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.73</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.78</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.73</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.48</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.73</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">100</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.73</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">6.00</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">6.09</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5.73</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">6.00</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">95</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.53</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.72</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.78</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.95</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.97</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.09</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">50,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.25</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.29</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.35</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">50,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.49</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">500,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.49</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.00</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">500,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.25</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.10</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">95</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">50,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">570,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.94</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.04</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.14</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.14</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.19</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.34</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.34</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.39</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.39</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.54</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.54</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.59</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.74</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.39</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.10</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">750,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.59</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.10</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">750,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.39</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.49</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.00</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.94</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">195</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.00</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.04</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">195</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.29</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.00</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">195</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.59</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.00</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">195</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.09</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.10</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">195</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.39</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.10</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1,495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.30</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">95</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.19</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4.30</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">195</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">95</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">var TgTableSort=window.TgTableSort||function(n,t){"use strict";function r(n,t){for(var e=[],o=n.childNodes,i=0;i<o.length;++i){var u=o[i];if("."==t.substring(0,1)){var a=t.substring(1);f(u,a)&&e.push(u)}else u.nodeName.toLowerCase()==t&&e.push(u);var c=r(u,t);e=e.concat(c)}return e}function e(n,t){var e=[],o=r(n,"tr");return o.forEach(function(n){var o=r(n,"td");t>=0&&t<o.length&&e.push(o[t])}),e}function o(n){return n.textContent||n.innerText||""}function i(n){return n.innerHTML||""}function u(n,t){var r=e(n,t);return r.map(o)}function a(n,t){var r=e(n,t);return r.map(i)}function c(n){var t=n.className||"";return t.match(/\S+/g)||[]}function f(n,t){return-1!=c(n).indexOf(t)}function s(n,t){f(n,t)||(n.className+=" "+t)}function d(n,t){if(f(n,t)){var r=c(n),e=r.indexOf(t);r.splice(e,1),n.className=r.join(" ")}}function v(n){d(n,L),d(n,E)}function l(n,t,e){r(n,"."+E).map(v),r(n,"."+L).map(v),e==T?s(t,E):s(t,L)}function g(n){return function(t,r){var e=n*t.str.localeCompare(r.str);return 0==e&&(e=t.index-r.index),e}}function h(n){return function(t,r){var e=+t.str,o=+r.str;return e==o?t.index-r.index:n*(e-o)}}function m(n,t,r){var e=u(n,t),o=e.map(function(n,t){return{str:n,index:t}}),i=e&&-1==e.map(isNaN).indexOf(!0),a=i?h(r):g(r);return o.sort(a),o.map(function(n){return n.index})}function p(n,t,r,o){for(var i=f(o,E)?N:T,u=m(n,r,i),c=0;t>c;++c){var s=e(n,c),d=a(n,c);s.forEach(function(n,t){n.innerHTML=d[u[t]]})}l(n,o,i)}function x(n,t){var r=t.length;t.forEach(function(t,e){t.addEventListener("click",function(){p(n,r,e,t)}),s(t,"tg-sort-header")})}var T=1,N=-1,E="tg-sort-asc",L="tg-sort-desc";return function(t){var e=n.getElementById(t),o=r(e,"tr"),i=o.length>0?r(o[0],"td"):[];0==i.length&&(i=r(o[0],"th"));for(var u=1;u<o.length;++u){var a=r(o[u],"td");if(a.length!=i.length)return}x(e,i)}}(document);document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(n){TgTableSort("tg-iE8pV")});</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated please :)

Comment: I would probably use a regular expression to remove the comma when comparing the values.  Beyond that it looks as if you've added a minified version of your javascript which makes it extremely difficult to help further.

Comment: Fix you javascript, don't include your minified version.

Comment: hmm I am not sure when that got minified! I might have to start the sorting from scratch, any idea of the easiest method please?

Comment: You can make use of something like jQuery's Table Sorter - http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can instead make use of a jQuery plugin called `tablesorter`, check documentation [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).. I've implemented your table with `tablesorter` and appears to work just fine.

You can sort multiple columns by pressing down the `shift` key then `left` clicking on multiple columns to sort.

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
);
```

```css
.tg {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-color: #999;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.tg td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
    border-color: #999;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #F7FDFA;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.tg th {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
    border-color: #999;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #26ADE4;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
th.tg-sort-header::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent;
}
th.tg-sort-header::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
th.tg-sort-header {
    cursor: pointer;
}
table th.tg-sort-header:after {
    content: '';
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-width: 0 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #404040 transparent;
    visibility: hidden;
}
table th.tg-sort-header:hover:after {
    visibility: visible;
}
table th.tg-sort-desc:after,
table th.tg-sort-asc:after,
table th.tg-sort-asc:hover:after {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
table th.tg-sort-desc:after {
    border-bottom: ;
    border-width: 4px 4px 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .tg {
        width: auto !important;
    }
    .tg col {
        width: auto !important;
    }
    .tg-wrap {
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        margin: auto 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/tablesorter/2.17.4/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter tg">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="tg-031e">Lender</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">Type</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">Initial Term (mths)</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">Initial Rate (%)</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">SVR (%)</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">Overall APR (%)</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">Fee (£)</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">LTV (%)</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">Max amount (£)</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">Max amount (£)</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">Monthly Repayment (£)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.98</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.98</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5.40</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
           
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5.48</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5.73</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5.90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">100</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5.73</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">6.00</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Aldermore</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">6.09</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5.73</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">6.00</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">95</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.53</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.72</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.78</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.95</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.97</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.09</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">50,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.25</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.29</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.35</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">50,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.49</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">999</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">500,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.49</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.00</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">500,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Barclays</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.25</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.10</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">95</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">50,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">570,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.94</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.04</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.14</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.14</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.19</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.34</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.34</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.39</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.70</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.39</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.54</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.54</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.59</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">2.74</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">85</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,000,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.39</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.10</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">750,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Halifax</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.59</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.10</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e">750,000</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.39</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.49</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.00</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1,495</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Tesco</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">Fixed</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">1.94</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">4.24</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">3.90</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">195</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">60</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
                <td class="tg-031e"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```